# Autodesk forge dashboard layup turn into blank after it showed for one time

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, dashboard, autodesk

I exactly follow the steps of tutorials from https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/dashboard and the lab lecture from the autodesk https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Learning-Lab-Your-first-Forge-Dashboard-2019#video. And the dashboard successfully showed for the first time. After I refreshed the pages for several times, the pie chart and bar chart disappeared, leaving the blank area. I repeated the same procesures again and still shows no dashboard.[the layup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o3qc.png)
Can somebody please tell the reason? Thank you.

Comment: please check the browser console, any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you haven't modified the source code in any way, there are many different reasons why the sample could break, for example, the server we download the charting library from could be temporarily down. Also, if you changed the size of the window, the charts could be *below* the viewer.

As Augusto mentioned in his comment, if you can still reproduce the issue with the sample code without any modifications, please check the browser [console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console) to see if there are any errors.